# Google Mod Page Speed (Leverage Browser Cache, Expiry Headers) for Lazy Loaded Images and Java Scripts

Tags: javascript, apache, centos6, cache-control, mod-pagespeed

I have been using google mod_page_speed about 3 years now, and I thinks its a great tool. The only problem I have with it is that it sets expiry header max-age:300 for images that are lazy loaded and the JavaScript files that are being loaded via "requirejs", which does not allow me to leverage browser caching as Pagespeed Insights calls it. Extend Cache filter does not work on these resources at all but it does on apply the correct headers on the resources that are loaded along with DOM.

When I switch off the page speed module the expiry headers perform as they should on every script and image including the lazy loaded ones. When I switch it back on it applies max-age:31536000 header to resources that are loaded along with the DOM, if they are retrieved after the DOM loaded it applies max-age:300. Very weird behavior.

Thanks.

Comment: you should try learning how to optimize using htaccess as opposed to things like pagespeed you'll end up with a cleaner fast optimization that doesn't cause you problems like this.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but I think that nobody would come out with the project such as mod page speed if it was better to do it yourself. I am pretty sure its possible, but definitely would require a lot of work to be put into it before it will start working as it should. Leveraging browser caching is not a problem, but minifying html and inlining small js files as well as css and combining them as well as optimizing images on fly, would be a bit more of a challennge

Comment: Its not out there because it can do it better. Its there so people can do it easily. there are plenty of tools out there that are just for ease. Learn some PHP & how to optimize with htaccess and some other points and you'd be sorted. If you want to understand the issue learn first how the plugin does what it does.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to receive a solution rather then a lecture, I know what you talk about but that has little help. Thanks anyway.

Comment: your probably better of contact the dev team directly via email and asking them why this bug happens they might not even know it exists.